# Teradata SQL Limit: Returning results When Limit reached

Tags: sql, view, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to run a simple query in Teradata SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
SAMPLE 5;
```

This works fine for small tables. However the Table I am querying is larger and *this query would take 10+ minutes to run*. I have also the same performance with using *TOP 5* instead of *SAMPLE 5*.

It seems that SAMPLE (and TOP) generates the entire Table, after that steps it selects 5 records that it returns.

**Question**: How do I ask the database Not to build the entire table, but rather only build it for any first 5 records it finds?

**EDIT**: The "Table" referred to is Actually a **View** and not a Table.

Comment: If `table` is actually a table it's fast. But if it's a view or a select with where, etc. it's creating the full answer set first, before applying TOP/SAMPLE.

Comment: Ok I checked and "The Table" is actually just a View.  If there is no way to limit a view as you are mentioning, then I can accept your answer.

Comment: To limit the volume being processed, you can specify a where condition on the projected columns of the view which may reduce the overhead and time it takes to render the TOP/SAMPLE. The effectiveness will depend on collected statistics, index coverage, and the complexity of the underlying view. Your mileage may vary.